# Struggling to understand FFT2 results in Python

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to do a Fourier transform on a concentration field to determine the mixing norm. The equation is below

[image: Mixing norm formula]

How do I extract the wave vector from the output? and what exactly does the output I get when I run the code below represent?

```py
for n in range(0, steps+1):
        conc_fft[:,:,n] = fft2(conc_full[:,:,n])
```

conc_full is a 50x50x1001 array, which gives us the concentration on a 2D grid for n time steps.

I don't know what to input in the final mixing norm formula (what sk and what k to use). Currently I'm using this:

```py
for n in range(0, steps+1):
    for i in range(0,z):
       for j in range(0,z):
            s_norm[n] = np.sqrt(np.sum((1/np.sqrt(1+i**2))*(conc_fft[i,j,n]**2)))
```

z is the grid size. 50x50 in my case.

Thank you!